# Android Bitmap Unwanted Black Border

Tags: android, image, bitmap, save, border

I have this bitmap on my imageview and when i save the bitmap, it includes the black border around the bitmap. The border is there because the size of the bitmap is different from the screensize. Anyone can tell me why and how to solve it? Thank you so much in advance!

Here's the screenshot of my image's Before and After : 
[image: img]

Here's my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectPhotoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Select Photo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/editPhotoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Edit Now" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

The imageview with problem is **imageView2**.

Here's how i save the image:

```
 private void savePhoto() {
    if (editPhotoImg.getDrawable() == null) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Photo Edited",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        try {
            String filePath = getOutputMediaFile(RESULT).getPath();
            editPhotoImg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = editPhotoImg.getDrawingCache(true);

            b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(
                    filePath));


            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Image saved to: "+filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // detectFaces(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid File       Path",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Once again thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: you can use scalyType="fitXY" but this will stretch the image and I guess the result will be worse. What is the goal? To stretch the image or just to fit it in the imageview? Or just play around with the scaleType to see if there will be suitable result for you.

Comment: Actually i want to save the image with its actual size without stretching it or adding the unwanted black border

Answer (score 1):

You have set

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      ... />
```

which stretches the image view to the bounds of its parent view (which doesn't guarantee that the image will have the same size as your parent view). If you don't want the black border, the view should have `"wrap_content"`, so it will be automatically sized for the loaded image.